# 2 errors messages in Blogspot

Tags: blogger, blogspot, error-messaging

I don't know how to code, so please give me detail answer so I can fix my blog.

here the errors message when I "inspect" my blog page

Message error number 1:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

message error number 2:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at repText (aplikasi-untuk-bisnis-online-maju-dan.html:1502)
    at aplikasi-untuk-bisnis-online-maju-dan.html:1502

what should I do to fix that? and if I ignore the errors messages is that okay or not okay?
Thank You

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your blog url or code.

Comment: Comment Post didn't show up when I access my blog from mobile

Comment: my blog is www.komputerkosan.com, and when I open a post via mobile https://www.komputerkosan.com/2018/11/aplikasi-untuk-bisnis-online-maju-dan.html, comment post didn't show up, but it showing up when I access on PC

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blog comments are hidden on mobile devices by the following CSS code

```
@media screen and (max-width:384px){
#comments,ul#related-summary li img{display:none}}
```

So you need to remove `#comments` selector from prev code in order to show comments on mobile or adding this code to override CSS rule

```
div#comments {
    display: block !important;
}
```